Websocket Connection failing on Deployed Azure web app
I am running a nodeJs server, and serving a ReactApp from it. This is deployed and hosted in an Azure WebApp.
I have container running a Django server, hosted on a separate Azure WebApp.
I am trying to open a WebSocket connection from my React app directly to my Django server.
I have tested this locally by deploying my Django app to azure, and then building my NodeJs & ReactApp LOCALLY and opening the wss:// connection and it works on my machine. But the after deploying the Node/React application to Azure the websocket connection fails with errorcode: 1006
I'm not sure what information settings would give more assistance in solving the issue.
I'm completely new to WebSockets as a whole. I'm hoping it's something to do with headers or protocols being stripped/changed as mentioned at the end of this article. But I cannot see anything in my Azure app configuration.
I can provide any further information (code or Azure configuration), I just don't know exactly what would help troubleshoot.
(My WS connection code, just for transparency)
export const awaitWsPing = () => {

  const socket = new WebSocket('wss://myDjangoApp.azurewebsites.net/my/ws/url');
  socket.onmessage = (e) => {

    const data = JSON.parse(e.data);

    console.log({data});
    notificationContext.setMessage('Received ping from server... closing ws');

    socket.close();
  };
  socket.onclose = (event) => {
    console.log('WebSocket closed: ', event);
  };
};

TIA for any assistance.

Can you share you github repo if possible?

What does your azure app service log stream show ?

I cannot, as it is internal.
But I can provide any information required, Neither log stream shows any problems.
The Django service isn't even receiving the request for the WS connection as far as I can see.

is there any solution? I am having the same issue, works locally but on Azure App Service it does not work
